# Page margin taking into account line number

Tags: margins, page-numbering

I am typesetting an application that has pretty strict formatting requirements, which includes 12pt Times New Roman font and a 1 inch margin on all 4 sides. I have the following in my preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[height=10in, width=8.5in, margin=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
```

I added the `\pagestyle{empty}` macro in an attempt to remove the page numbers at the bottom of the page and make sure it's a 1 inch margin. However, it appears that this macro did not remove the page number, it simply made it invisible. There is still a 1 inch margin between the edge of the page and where the page number used to appear, and an additional margin directly below the main text, making the bottom margin about 1.75 inches. How can I completely remove the page number and ensure the bottom margin of the page is 1 inch?

PS. I measured the margin on a printed test page and it's actually very close to a 1.25 inch margin. I don't think this will be a problem, but is there a way to make this more precise?

PSS. Unfortunately, my problem was a silly one: I had set my height to 10in when I in fact meant 11in. However, your helpful responses taught me a few things: the difference between height/width and paperheight/paperwidth, and also the letterpaper shortcut for the 8.5x11in dimensions. Thanks!

Comment: [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) has an additional `includeheadfoot` option to include the header/footer in the layout settings. Have you tried to add this?

Comment: The unprecise printing is likely the result of a print driver that compensates for the fact that the printer cannot print to the edges and shrinkes the page, so that the entire document fits on the page. It makes no sense to change this in your document, change you print settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem may well be that you've specified `height=10in` as one of the arguments of the `geometry` package; it should be `height=11in`, shouldn't it? (I noted you also specified `width=8.5in`.)

If so, it suffices to specify `margin=1in` as the argument for the `geometry` package and to specify `letterpaper` as an argument when the `documentclass` is specified.

Comment: Writing `margin=1in` only is sufficient

Comment: @egreg: Assuming the actual papersize is US Letter (8.5" x 11"), either `height=10in` is 1" too small (if it refers to the sheet's dimension), or it's 1" too large (if it refers to the height of the textblock). Given that the OP also specified `width=8.5in`, I assume it's the former interpretation that he/she has in mind.

Comment: Probably the OP is mistaking `height` and `width` for `paperheight` and `paperwidth`.

Comment: @egreg Indeed that was the case.

Answer (score 4):

use the option `showframe` for geometry then you'll see your current margins.
Alternetively use package `layout` and the macro of the same name which shows you the defined layout with the values for the margins:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[height=10in, width=8.5in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following call will accomplish your needs

```
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
```

assuming you're using US Letter paper. The calculations by *geometry* give

```
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
```

that correspond to a width of 6.5in and a height of 9in, leaving exactly 1in on all four sides. The page number (if not suppressed) will appear in the 1in lower margin.

You might want to add the option `heightrounded` that will reduce the text height to 460pt, a difference of 0.135in that's almost unnoticeable and will help to fit better the text.